# How to debug Reflexil

Tags: reflexil

Reflexil (http://reflexil.net/) is an assembly editor and runs as a plug-in for Red Gate's Reflector and Telerik's JustDecompile.

Since it's a plug-in for Reflector and provided with source code, I want to debug it and set a break point in the source code to learn how it works. But I can not make the break point is hit. I tried run Debug in Reflexil project and attach to Reflector process, but Visual Studio tell me the symbol is not loaded and the break point would hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you just have to attach to Reflector, running Reflexil.

But Reflector must use the DLL you are building within Visual Studio (in Plugins/REflexil.Reflector/Debug)

Regards

Seb

Comment: Get the answer for the author of Relflexil.